# Dúvida sobre o funcionamento do BaseAdapter e da ListView

Tags: android, android-adapter

Meu código é o seguinte: no método *`getView`* do meu `BaseAdapter`, eu adiciono todas as views criadas à uma lista (preciso disso para fazer uma certa coisa). Nesse mesmo BaseAdapter, eu tenho um método *`getQuantViews`* que retorna quantas views foram adicionadas à essa lista.

No meu fragment, eu uso o `listview.setAdapter` para criar as views e em seguida, eu chamo o tal método *`getQuantViews`* do meu `BaseAdapter` para saber quantas views foram adicionadas e exibo isso em um Log.

Ao carregar o `ListView`, percebo no log que a ordem dos processos não está acontecendo corretamente, pois no log, primeiro é chamado o *`getQuantViews`* e depois que se entra no *`getView`*.

Cometi algum erro na ordem dos processos? Pois, ao meu ver, primeiro ele entraria no *getView* ao usar o *setAdapter* e só depois que ele chamaria o *getQuantViews*. Tentei também separar os processos, colocando o *`setAdapter`* no *`onStart`* e depois chamar o *`getQuantViews`* no *`onResume`*, mas o resultado foi o mesmo.

No Base Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Trial t = listTrial.get(position);
    View layout;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_trial, null);
    } else {
        layout = convertView;
    }

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.00");

    linkViews(layout);

    tv_trial_name.setText(t.getName());
    tv_trial_date.setText(t.getDate());
    tv_trial_hour.setText(t.getHour());
    tv_peak_force.setText(
            layout.getResources().getString(R.string.text_peak_force) + ":  " + df.format(t.getPeakForce()));
    tv_comments.setText(t.getComment());

    this.listViews.add(layout);
    Log.v("Bio", "listViews size: " + this.listViews.size());

    return layout;
}

public int getQuantViews() {
    return this.listViews.size();
}
```

No Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    loadTrials();
    super.onStart();
    Log.v("Bio", "onStart");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v("Bio", "onResume");
    check();
}
```

- O método loadTrials seta o baseadapter:

  ```
  private void loadTrials() {
      tAdapter = new TrialAdapter(view.getContext(), list_trials);
      lv_trials.setAdapter(tAdapter);
  }
  ```
- O método check mostra a quantidade de views da lista

  ```
  public void check() {
      Log.v("Bio", "Retorno: " + tAdapter.getQuantViews());
  }
  ```

Comment: A dúvida é se o `onResume` deveria rodar antes do `onStart`? Acho que não, isso não acontece por causa do ciclo de vida da [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). Além disso o `getView` é chamado pelo `ListView` e isso é feito em alguma das primeiras passadas de layout (não garanto que seja a primeira).

Comment: Não, a dúvida é porque ele está chamando o .getQuantViews() se antes ele teria que passar pelo GetView do BaseAdapter para criar os layouts

Comment: O método `getView()` do *Adapter* só é chamado quando a *ListView* necessita de fazer o *display* de uma linha na tela e não quando o `setAdapter() é chamado.

Comment: então como eu faria para chamar meu método *getQuantViews* depois que todos os itens fossem exibidos?

Comment: Mesmo não sabendo o que você quer fazer com essa lista suponho que, preenche-la no método `getView()`, não irá fazer o que você quer já que ele é chamado sempre que é necessário fazer o *display* de uma linha. Sempre que for feito *scroll* o método será chamado e serão adicionados novos itens, ela irá crescer indefinidamente e terá itens repetidos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o metodo getCount do base adapter e verificar se a posicao atual do getView é igual ao valor retornado pelo getCount, caso seja igual você terá chegado no fim da lista. Essa comparação seria feita dentro do próprio getView onde vc poderia estar exibindo o log de acordo com sua necessidade.